# Convert javax.jms.Message to com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

**Schema**:

> com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage jtm ---> f(javax.jms.Message m)

I receive a `JMSTextMessage`, but my function parameter is an interface (`Message`). `JMSTextMessage` added a function: `getText()` that doesn't exist in `Message`.

```
com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage implements javax.jms.Message
```

How can I call that `getText()` method in my `f` function? Is there a method / cast that has to be done?

Of course that `m.getText()` will not work because `getText()` doesn't exist in `Message`.

**URLs**:

[JMSTextMessage](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/jms/JMSTextMessage.html)

[Message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your m object is an instance of JMSTextMessage (you might want to have a instanceof call to check) then you can just cast it and then call the getText method like this:

```
(JMSTextMessage)m).getText()
```

However, you probably don't want to cast it to the actual implementation as this then restricts the portability of your code (i.e. you would have to rewrite your code for Weblogic for example). So it is better to cast your Message object to the javax.jms.TextMessage interface like this:

```
(TextMessage)m).getText()
```

Comment: I checked that `m` is `instanceof` `TextMessage` and that I used the second approach. Thanks!

Comment: i am facing an exception while casting to TextMessage "com.ibm.jms.JMSBytesMessage incompatible with javax.jms.TextMessage", while i am trying it as said above in this solution, getText() is actually returning a String and it cannot be converted to TextMessage , can you suggest please ?

Comment: @rinilnath in this case you have a JMSBytesMessage and not a TextMessage, you must read the bytes from the BytesMessage and then you can create the String from that.